# android Fragment Added but not visible

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm currently facing an issue I cannot understand.
The situation here is :
I have a FragmentActivity which contains a Main fragment.
Inside this fragment there are 3 fragments, each one placed inside it's own layout, all visible at first sight. In fact they are like this :

A|B|C|

To add and replace the fragments inside these layouts I'm using the childFragmentManager.
Everything works fine when I'm using it. But when I'm changing the device orientation, the fragment is not displayed but is added (isAdded() method return true) and no error is shown.

Note : I'm replacing the concerned fragments when the orientation is changed so I really don't understand what the problem may be.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Paste some code please.

Comment: Do you have `setRetainInstance(true);` in your `onCreate` method?

Comment: Add    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" property under Activity in manifest to retain state on orientation change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks adding android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" works.