# Android retain Fragment not visible after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-orientation

I try to reduce my view hierarchy and use the android.R.id.content view to add a Fragment which use setRetainInstance( true ) to keep its instance alive.

My activity is very simple

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( final Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        // ensure that the view is available if we add the fragment
        findViewById( android.R.id.content ).post( new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // add the fragment only once to manager
                if( savedInstanceState == null ) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .add( android.R.id.content, new LoginFragment() )
                        .commit();
                }
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

The Fragment create its own view and use the setRetainInstance(true) method in onCreate().
My problem is that after a orientation change my fragment isn't re-added to the activity and the activity is empty.

Comment: I found the solution by myself here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351336/android-fragment-added-but-not-visible. But in my opinion its a strange behaviour.

Comment: The reason it work because activity do not get kill. Unless you have a very good reason, you should allow activity to be kill and re-create when orientation change.

Answer (score 1):

savedInstanceState may not be null after you rotate screen, so fragment did not add to the activity.

Although the fragment itself do not get killed, but activity get killed and you have to re-add the fragment to activity again.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentWithTag("TAG");
if(fragment == null){
    fragment = new LoginFragment();
}else{
    fm.beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "TAG")
        .commit();
}
```

By the way, setRetainInstance(true) is not meant to use this way. You should allow fragment to get kill and re-create along with activity.